# MobileFirst - captured video is always at 4:3 screen ratio

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm developing web app that records a video for send it with other info to my server.
The problem is that the video captured is always at 4:3 screen ratio. Video recorded with native stock app are widescreen. I get this behavior both in Android and in iOS.

I tried also third-party plugin VideoCapturePlus that gives the HD quality option, but the video still has the same screen ratio problem.

Is it a Cordova problem or there's a way to do widescreen (16:9) video with MFP, like stock camera app?

Comment: MFP is not doing anything at that layer. There is either Cordova implementation or Native implementation. I suggest that you will create a pure Cordova app (that is, without MFP) and see if it happens there as well. If it happens there as well, this relates to Cordova and not to MFP. I am therefore removing the MFP tag until proven otherwise.

Comment: Hi, pure Cordova app works well, the video is correctly captured in widescreen. But I still think it's a problem of MFP because it provides a Cordova version that has this problem. If I have to use MFP for make my app, how can I solve this issue? It's not possible to update Cordova version...

Comment: Please mention which MFP version you are using where it fails, and which pure Cordova version you are using where it works. Also supply both both working and non-working projects, you can upload to Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Hi Idan, I use MFP 7.1 for the project and Cordova 5.3.3 for pure Cordova project.
- MFP project (4:3 video captured): https://www.dropbox.com/s/456m0fgn8rhzz18/VideoCapture_MFP_71.zip?dl=0
- Cordova project (widescreen video captured): https://www.dropbox.com/s/nr3a0356f85zvrx/Video.7z?dl=0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a defect in the provided Cordova version in MobileFirst apps; to receive further help and have the development team research a fix, you will need to open a PMR (support ticket) for IBM. Once you open the PMR, provide its number here.